# SQLDependency firing multiple times when more than 1 connection made

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I'm in the process of developing an appointment schedule for our company in `ASP.NET (MVC Razor)`. I'm using `SQLDependency` so the pages can update via the service broker. We currently have 15 service centres, and each of them may have 1 to 4 computers where they can take calls and insert/modify/delete appointments. Our customers also have the option to take an online appointment with our online appointment tool, so this is why we need it to be dynamic and constantly refresh so we don't book 2 customers at the same time.

So far, everything is working fine. The page constantly refreshes when needed and we were two days away of launching our new tool. Except, when making tests in a production environment (we're switching our current tool to a new server, so we're testing it before going live with it), we realized that when 2 connections are made to the website, the `SQLDependency` act crazy. It will double the notifications everytime (once the first time, twice at the second notification, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc... so it escalates quickly) and so, it just becomes useless as it refreshes the partial view too many times. I was wondering if I was missing something. Here's some snippet of code :

First, the javascript call :

```
$(function () {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    var notifications = $.connection.rendezVousHub;

    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    notifications.client.updateAgenda = function () {
        getAllRdv()
    };

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
       getAllRdv();
    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert(e);
    });
});
```

The `C#` function that have the `SQLDependency` call and command

```
public IEnumerable<RendezVousModels> GetAllRdv(DateTime date, int whsCode)
{
    _date = date;
    _whsCode = whsCode;

    string query = @"[dbo].[InfosAgenda]";

    var rdv = new List<RendezVousModels>();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Notification = null;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date.ToShortDateString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhsCode", whsCode);

            dependancy = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependancy.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                rdv.Add(item: new RendezVousModels
                {
                    // set infos into Model
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return rdv;
}
```

The `onChange` event function :

```
private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;
    dependancy.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;

    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        RendezVousHub.sendAgenda();

    GetAllRdv(_date, _whsCode);
}
```

I'm running out of ideas here. Maybe they all need different connections? If so, how should I proceed?

Thanks